# Regex to remove word from different positions

Tags: r, regex, string

I am pretty regex-blind so I was looking for a way to uniformly remove the word **remove** from the following string

```
x <- c('something,remove', 'remove, something', 'something, remove, somethingElse,alsoThis')
```

and get the result,
`'something', 'something', 'something, somethingElse, alsoThis'`

I can do it with `strsplit` but I was wondering for the regex version too

```
sapply(strsplit(x, ', |,'), function(i)paste(i[i != 'remove'], collapse = ', '))
#[1] "something"    "something"   "something, somethingElse, alsoThis"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a base R solution using `gsub()`:

```r
x <- c('something,remove', 'remove, something', 'something, remove, somethingElse,alsoThis')
output <- gsub("^,|,$", "", gsub(",?\\s*\\bremove,?\\s*", ",", x))
output

[1] "something"                        "something"
[3] "something,somethingElse,alsoThis"
```

The inner call to `gsub()` removes `remove` along with leading/trailing whitespace and commas.  The outer call to `gsub()` is a cleanup to remove any possible leading/trailing commas.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution, based on `stringr::str_remove`:

```r
library(stringr)

str_remove(x, "\\,*remove\\,*\\s*")

#> [1] "something"                         "something"                        
#> [3] "something, somethingElse,alsoThis"
```

Comment: will this regex work in `gsub` too? I d rather not use packages

Comment: Yes, @Sotos. Give me a minute.

Comment: Now, you have @TimBiegeleisen's solution, that does that.